# How to run thousands of dos commands

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of thousands of del commands to run. The commands are fully formatted and ready to go in a text file. While I know some batch I have never run a command imported from another file. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have them in the file and ready to go, you simply need to change the file extension to ".bat" and run the file.  You can do this by double clicking on it or by running it from the command line.

Comment: Easier than you thought, eh?

Comment: Yep. All 600000 commands are now being executed. So easy. #headpalmMoments

Comment: I guess if I was doing that I would consider iterating through the lines of the text file and add error checking (stop and display or at least log errors) unless you don't care about errors. You could also generate a log if that would be useful for historical purposes. If you need that, post a snippet of the text file.

Comment: @RGuggisberg to log all messages and errors: maybe `myscript.bat>mylog.txt 2>&1`?

Comment: Can you redirect stderr at a Windows command prompt?  I've never tried.  @josefZ

Comment: Cool.  Clearly I've been doing this for far too long.  I wonder when that got added in!